# Есть ли стандартный метод такому коду?

Tags: python

Знаю, что есть **.__ getattribute__()**, но он ругается если нет поля у объекта.

Решил реализовать так:

```
def my_getattribute(obj, key):
    return obj.__getattribute__(key) if key in obj.__dir__() else None


class SampleClass():
    id = '123'


s = int(10)
s2 = SampleClass()

print(my_getattribute(s, 'id'))  #None
print(my_getattribute(s2, 'id')) #123
```

Сам вопрос: есть ли более оптимальный способ или стандартный метод (на подобии .get() у словаря), а то тут получается, что я 2 раза пробегаю по полям объекта

Comment: Вместо пробегания 2 раза можно просто отловить исключение AttributeError (впрочем, код всё равно получится громоздкий)

Comment: И да, если вдруг объект переопределяет методы `__getattr__` и/или `__getattribute__`, то он может генерировать условно бесконечное количество полей, которые не будет видно в dir, так что, возможно, перехват исключения это единственное правильное решение

Comment: Кстати, не стоит забывать (я вот забыл), что есть просто обычная функция getattr: `getattr(s2, 'id', None)`

Comment: @andreymal, Спасибо! Это как раз то, что я искал!